# Need to list count of individual special characters in the student table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
studentname    marks
B@lu            20
T)m             100
J#hn            45
Tim*@           20
```

Output of `studentname`  column should list count of special characters (**@, ), ), #, ***)

```
Type    count
@        2
)        1
#        1
*        1
```

So basically I want to count the number of times these characters were repeated in the table and then show it on another table.

List of special characters : -!#%&+,./:;<=>@`{|}~"()*\_\^\?[]\''

Comment: What are you defining a "special character" to be?  What have you attempted on your own?  We aren't a "do my work for me" site.

Comment: This is a strange requirement that has all the appearance of very derived problem from a teacher who doesn't understand that in the real world this kind of query just isn't ever needed.

Comment: special characters means all the  special symbols listed in the keyboard

Comment: What keyboard? Can you type them out and include the entire list in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the following...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#SpecialCharacter', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #SpecialCharacter;

CREATE TABLE #SpecialCharacter (
    SpecialChar CHAR(1) NOT NULL 
    );
INSERT #SpecialCharacter (SpecialChar) VALUES
    ('-'), ('!'), ('#'), ('%'), ('&'), ('+'), (','), 
    ('.'), ('/'), (':'), (';'), ('<'), ('='), ('>'), 
    ('@'), ('`'), ('{'), ('|'), ('}'), ('~'), ('"'), 
    ('('), (')'), ('*'), ('\'), ('_'), ('\'), ('^'), 
    ('\'), ('?'), ('['), (']'), ('\'), ('''');

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Student', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #Student;

CREATE TABLE #Student (
    StudentName  VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL 
    );
INSERT #Student (StudentName) VALUES
    ('B@lu'),
    ('T)m%'),
    ('J#h_n'),
    ('Tim*@'),
    ('J@@@&&&oN');

--========================================================
SELECT 
    sc.SpecialChar,
    CharCount = SUM(cc.CharCount)
FROM 
    #SpecialCharacter sc
    JOIN #Student s
        ON s.StudentName LIKE '%' + sc.SpecialChar + '%' 
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (LEN(s.StudentName) - LEN(REPLACE(s.StudentName, sc.SpecialChar, '')) ) ) cc (CharCount)
GROUP BY
    sc.SpecialChar
HAVING 
    SUM(cc.CharCount) > 0;
```

Result...

```
SpecialChar CharCount
----------- -----------
#           1
%           1
&           3
)           1
*           1
@           5
_           1
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following should do it.

```
DECLARE @YourTable TABLE(StudentName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL );

INSERT @YourTable
       (StudentName)
VALUES ('B@lu'),
       ('T)m'),
       ('J#hn'),
       ('Tim*@'),
       ('-!#%&+,./:;<=>@`{|}~"()*_^?[]\''');

SELECT letter,
       COUNT(*) AS [count]
FROM   @YourTable
       JOIN master..spt_values
         ON Type = 'P'
            AND number BETWEEN 1 AND LEN(studentname)
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT SUBSTRING(StudentName, number, 1)) CA(letter)
WHERE  letter LIKE '[!-#%-/:;-?@[-`{-~]' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2
GROUP  BY letter
ORDER  BY [count] DESC
```

Comment: I think that instead of a defined list of characters we could evaluate the ascii value. This would at least minimize this to less a zillion characters to type. It would be a few ranges assuming that 0-9, a-z and A-Z are the only valid characters. Anything else would be counted. Somewhat depends on what is defined as a special character which to go on that.

Comment: Yep, as I only have access to rextester etc at the moment I'll leave figuring out the ASCII ranges as an exercise for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

assuming there is a table with all interested special characters called `TableSpecialChar`

```
select a.char 'type', count(*) 'Count' from TableSpecialChar a
inner join TableStudent b on b.name like '%['+a.char+']%'
group by a.char
```

Comment: If a character is repeated in a name this will only count it once. It also doesn't deal correctly with characters such as `%` and `_` that have special significance in the `LIKE` syntax.

Comment: special characters are escaped now in LIKE. About characters repetitions in a name, it should be addressed differently.